# How to generate languages query method codes for firestore query protos?

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore, protocol-buffers, grpc

I'm developing a desktop application with firestore database in java.
I want to generate query method for specific programming languages that supports protobuf.
My question is is there any way to auto generate query function or methods using google protobuf framework?

In java

```
Query query= db.collection("col2").whereGreaterThanOrEqualTo(name, "a").orderBy(name, Direction.ASCENDING).limit(50);
RunQueryRequest  runQueryRequest = query.toProto();
StructuredQuery structuredQuery = runQueryRequest.getStructuredQuery();
System.out.println("structuredQuery: " + structuredQuery);
```

This code prints some proto formatted string like

```
from {
  collection_id: "col2"
}
where {
  field_filter {
    field {
      field_path: "name"
    }
    op: GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL
    value {
      string_value: "a"
    }
  }
}
order_by {
  field {
    field_path: "name"
  }
  direction: ASCENDING
}
limit {
  value: 50
}
```

I just want convert above java code to other languages using this proto string. But I don't know how to do it. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Google (increasingly) uses Protobuf to define the types for its APIs even though the majority of its services continue to expose REST endpoints (only a few are gRPC). Using Protobuf provides a mechanism for defining types one e.g. [`query.proto`](https://github.com/googleapis/googleapis/blob/master/google/firestore/v1/query.proto) and using these in any language (particularly those languages it supports in its SDKs). With the REST endpoints, the libraries marshal the protos are JSON and ship them to/from servers.

Comment: I was unaware of the [`toProto`](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-firestore/latest/com.google.cloud.firestore.Query#com_google_cloud_firestore_Query_toProto__) until your question and think this -- and related -- method(s) aren't surfaced in every Firestore language client (e.g. not in [Go](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#Query) or [Python](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/firestore/latest/google.cloud.firestore_v1.query.Query#google_cloud_firestore_v1_query_Query_get)).

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but you've three options. Where not surfaced through the SDK, use the generated proto bindings to marshal|unmarshal queries as binary protos. Or, perhaps more simply JSON format the protos. The text format that you include in your questions isn't as common and may be more challenging to use.

Comment: Actually, the Go library does include [`Deserialize`](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#Query.Deserialize) and [`Serialize`](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/firestore#Query.Serialize) methods described "This could be useful, for instance, if executing a query formed in one process in another."

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using java String.format and StructuredQuery class.
Thanks all for answer.